# Does the package robot_localization need the position transform between sensors?

Tags: ros, navigation, robot-localization, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My robot has a IMU sensor and a GPS.Now I want to use the package `robot_localization`.

How have I published the position transform?

For instance,I set the frame_id of IMU sensor to 'imu', set the frame_id of GPS to 'gps' and the robot's frame_id is 'base_link'.

So I publish the transform to the node `/tf`:

For IMU sensor,`frame_id` is 'base_link' and `child_frame_id` is 'imu', x:... y:... z:...

For GPS,`frame_id` is 'base_link' and `child_frame_id` is 'gps', x:... y:... z:...

Am I right?Will the robot_localization package automatically acquire these transforms when doing merging?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412829/does-the-package-robot_localization-need-the-position-transform-between-sensors?/) by [peter_feng](https://answers.ros.org/users/140466/peter_feng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best is probably to have all these frames defined in a URDF. This is basically the model of your robot.

[robot_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher) can parse it and publish both the fixed and time-varying transforms.

---

Originally posted by [Olivier Kermorgant](https://answers.ros.org/users/11856/olivier-kermorgant/) with karma: 280 on 2023-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2023-06-05**:
Yes, this is the correct way to go, @peter_feng, and the EKF will still work with the transforms when they are defined this way.

**Comment by [chased11](https://answers.ros.org/users/115712/chased11/) on 2023-06-05**:
Does using the static transform publishers from base_link to imu_link and gps_link not suffice? (i.e. define base_link as COR and broadcast static transform between [-0.5,0,0] if IMU is 0.5 m behind the COR)

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2023-06-06**:
Yes, using a `static_transform_publisher` is fine, and was my original suggestion, but putting together a URDF model for your bot is always a good idea.